# Neo4j "database killed" trying to install neosemantics plugin on macos

Tags: macos, plugins, neo4j

On macosx 10.13.4, neo4j 3.3.5, I am trying to start up Neo4j after adding the neosemantics plugin. Before starting, I downloaded the jar file neosemantics-3.3.0.2.jar from https://github.com/jbarrasa/neosemantics/releases and added two lines to the bottom of neo4j.conf

```
dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=semantics.extension=/rdf
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=semantics.*
```

**Error message**

> "Database killed ..." appears on the screen

**The neo4j.log file shows:**

```
Starting Neo4j.
2018-05-14 13:49:08.954+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.3.5 ========
2018-05-14 13:49:09.003+0000 INFO  Starting...
2018-05-14 13:49:10.410+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 127.0.0.1:7687.
2018-05-14 13:49:10.448+0000 INFO  Initiating metrics...
2018-05-14 13:49:15.475+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3dc4ed6f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty$Delegating overrides final method getDeclaringClass.()Ljava/lang/Class;". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3dc4ed6f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty$Delegating overrides final method getDeclaringClass.()Ljava/lang/Class;".
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3dc4ed6f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty$Delegating overrides final method getDeclaringClass.()Ljava/lang/Class;".
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:220)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
        at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.CommercialEntryPoint.main(CommercialEntryPoint.java:22)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3dc4ed6f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty$Delegating overrides final method getDeclaringClass.()Ljava/lang/Class;".
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:212)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /Users/colingoldberg/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-c4c8aad5-ff29-431c-8c33-0144b82bcf5a/installation-3.3.5/data/databases/graph.db
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:211)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.enterprise.EnterpriseGraphDatabase.<init>(EnterpriseGraphDatabase.java:36)
        at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.lambda$static$1(OpenEnterpriseNeoServer.java:75)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:88)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures@50dd1e3a' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty$Delegating overrides final method getDeclaringClass.()Ljava/lang/Class;".
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:207)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty$Delegating overrides final method getDeclaringClass.()Ljava/lang/Class;
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader$1.fetchNextOrNull(ProcedureJarLoader.java:141)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader$1.fetchNextOrNull(ProcedureJarLoader.java:118)
        at org.neo4j.collection.PrefetchingRawIterator.peek(PrefetchingRawIterator.java:50)
        at org.neo4j.collection.PrefetchingRawIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingRawIterator.java:36)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProcedures(ProcedureJarLoader.java:91)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProceduresFromDir(ProcedureJarLoader.java:82)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.start(Procedures.java:276)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
        ... 11 more
2018-05-14 13:49:15.477+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you by chance have apoc plugin too? I just figured out that APOC has some conflicts with a few plugins.